How to show the latest commit id in GitHub Workflow run-name?
I almost have this with
run-name: Build ${{ github.sha }}@${{ github.ref_name }}

Outputs: Build de12as23saw12asd123...@master
But github.sha has full commit sha. I just need the first 6 characters of this.

Is there a way to get the latest commit id?

OR
Is there a way to trim string inside YAML file?
So that it just shows: Build de12as@master

Seems like there is no substring function available in GH
